# $.focus() doesn't work when focus is on html canvas (with fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs, fabricjs2

So i have a text element on the canvas with fabricjs, when clicked on the text box some jquery fires and part of that code is supposed to push the cursor focus to a textarea while maintaining the active canvas object (the object stays selected just fine when i click into the textarea).

The problem is that the focus isn't being put to the textarea.

So if we have textarea with id "editing-box" and run something like this:

```
fabric.on('object:selected',function(e){

    // set textbox to edit mode here

    // focus on textbox
    if(the object is textbox){
        $('#editing-box').focus();
    }
});
```

The fabric textbox goes into editing fine but the texarea doesn't take the focus for the typing.